Reset cumulative sum in Polars DataFrame when exceeding a threshold
I am working with a Polars DataFrame and need to compute a cumulative sum of data values that resets whenever the cumulative sum exceeds a specific threshold, (absolute value). Here is an example of the DataFrame structure and the expected output:
┌───────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ flag  ┆ data_value ┆ cum_sum  │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ i64   ┆ i64        ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ -1    ┆ 10         ┆ -10      │
│ 1     ┆ 15         ┆ 5        │
│ 1     ┆ 20         ┆ 25       │
│ -1    ┆ 30         ┆ -5       │
│ 1     ┆ 10         ┆ 5        │ 
│ 1     ┆ 30         ┆ 35       │ <-- Reset because abs(35) >= 30
│ -1    ┆ 10         ┆ -10      │ <-- New sum starts after reset
│ 1     ┆ 7          ┆ 3        │
└───────┴────────────┴──────────┘

In this table, cumsum = flag * data_value. The cumulative sum should reset if the absolute value of cum_sum reaches or exceeds 30 in this case.
I am looking for a vectorized way or a function in Polars to handle this conditional reset efficiently without having to loop through the rows, if possible at all.

You can't vectorize a cum_sum with reset by threshold. This operation is inherently iterative.
Thus, the only option is a loop. I'm not aware of a polars internal method to achieve this.
A possibility would be to use compiled code with numba:
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def cum_sum_reset(col, threshold=30):
    total = 0
    out = []
    for x in col:
        total = total+x
        out.append(total)
        if abs(total) >= threshold:
            total = 0
    return out

df.with_columns((pl.col('flag')*pl.col('data_value'))
                .map_batches(lambda x: pl.Series(cum_sum_reset(x.to_numpy())))
                .alias('cum_sum')
               )

Output:
┌──────┬────────────┬─────────┐
│ flag ┆ data_value ┆ cum_sum │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---     │
│ i64  ┆ i64        ┆ i64     │
╞══════╪════════════╪═════════╡
│ -1   ┆ 10         ┆ -10     │
│ 1    ┆ 15         ┆ 5       │
│ 1    ┆ 20         ┆ 25      │
│ -1   ┆ 30         ┆ -5      │
│ 1    ┆ 10         ┆ 5       │
│ 1    ┆ 30         ┆ 35      │
│ -1   ┆ 10         ┆ -10     │
│ 1    ┆ 7          ┆ -3      │
└──────┴────────────┴─────────┘

Timings:
# 8M rows
418 ms ± 13.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# 80M rows
4.07 s ± 107 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Testing sample:
N = 10_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame({'flag': [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1]*N,
                   'data_value': [10, 15, 20, 30, 10, 30, 10, 7]*N,
                  })


Oh wow.. that looks like a great alternative! Thank you very much!
